# AppleScriptObjC - correct syntax for checking the window title string in an IF statement

Tags: applescript, applescript-objc

I'm trying to build an if statement in AppleScriptObjC that checks whether the title of a window matches a certain string, but I'm not sure of the correct syntax.

For example:

```
theWindow's setTitle_("testing")

if theWindow's title = "testing" then
  do some stuff
else
  do some other stuff
end if
```

That's obviously not the correct syntax but hopefully it demonstrates what I'm after.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine resolved this:

```
theWindow's setTitle_("testing")

set testTitle to theWindow's |title|() as string 

if testTitle = "Testing" then 
  do some stuff 
else 
  do some other stuff 
end if
```